# New HVAC installed

Tags: hvac, installation

I just had a new HVAC system installed and the contractor installed in on a pounding raining stormy day.  I am thinking that was a bad decision on his part.  Now my home has a musty smell and air seems drier than when I had my older system. Would you expect air quality problems because of this installation.  Thinking I should have my air quality tested.  Also when I read on line it says 78 should be a comfortable degree I need to leave mine on 72 to get some air on second floor, does this seem unreasonable.  Should contractor adjust something on system to get more flow upstairs.  Any ideas on how to keep air temperature more even throughout the house. Thank you, Debbie

Comment: Are there "conditioned" air delivery points in each room or on each floor? If so, this makes control **so** much easier.

Comment: There are a couple of non-sequiturs up there. First, is this an exterior system? What difference does it make that it was raining? Please revise to clarify that. Then, installed in the wet but resulting in dry air? I'm confused. Finally, the temp and airflow thing seems completely unrelated. Please revise again to explain what sort of HVAC system this is and how it's configured. We don't have much at all to go on here.

Comment: You've got a LOT of different things here. I'd say a "ton", but that is something you need to tell us - how big is the A/C (measured in "tons" or "BTU")? How big is the house? When it is 72 downstairs, what is the temperature upstairs? An A/C system cools air and dries it (effectively) at the same time. So if it is too large then it might "dry" too much. If the air flow is not balanced well, you might have one floor much colder than another.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. As the others have said, we'll need more information before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: **How do you perceive the presence of rain outside to have affected the installation of the HVAC**. *"Air seems drier"*  Did the old system have a humidifier and the new does not.? *"Would you expect air quality problems because of this installation"* We do not what your installation consisted of.  ? *"Should contractor adjust something on system to get more flow upstairs"* We do not know what your system is.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to have your ducts tested and resealed. Leaky ducts can allow musty air from a basement or else where in, and results in low output in parts of the house. Causing warm/cool spots.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.